# Java change system new-line character

Tags: java, windows, unix, newline, text-formatting

On Windows, using `System.out.println()` prints out `\n\r` while on a Unix system you would get `\n`.

Is there any way to tell java what new-line characters you want to use?

Comment: `String NEWLINE = "\n\r";` or whatever you want, followed by
`System.out.print("yourString"+NEWLINE);`

Comment: That's a workaround that does work but can't you explicitly tell java what environment you want to target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated by others, the system property `line.separator` contains the actual line separator. Strangely, the other answers missed the simple conclusion: you can override that separator by changing that system property at startup time.

E.g. if you run your program with the option `-Dline.separator=X` at the command line you will get the funny behavior of `System.out.println(…);` ending the line with an `X`.

The tricky part is how to specify characters like `\n` or `\r` at the command line. But that’s system/environment specific and not a Java question anymore.

Comment: you can specify newline as follows `-Dline.separator=$'\n'`

Comment: @Andreas +1. bit the $'\n' usage implies a bash shell, and that requires IFS=' ' also to be set, otherwise the newline may be treated as whitespace and discarded.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way and I've just tried it.

There is a system property `line.separator`. You can set it using `System.setProperty("line.separator", whatever)`

To be sure that it indeed causes JVM to use other separator I implemented the following exercise:

```
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:/temp/mytest.txt"));
    writer.println("hello");
    writer.println("world");
    writer.close();
```

I am running on windows now, so the result was 14 bytes long file:

```
03/27/2014  10:13 AM                14 mytest.txt
               1 File(s)             14 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  409,157,980,160 bytes free
```

However when I added the following line to the beginning of my code:

```
    System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
```

I got 14 bytes long file:

03/27/2014  10:13 AM                14 mytest.txt
               1 File(s)             14 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  409,157,980,160 bytes free

I opened this file with notepad that does not recognize single `\n` as a new line and saw one-line text `helloworld` instead of 2 separate lines. So, this works.

Comment: Confirmed by piping through to `od` in cywgin. Thanx a bunch!

Comment: +1 If you were a few minutes faster I had skipped writing my own answer… However, it’s worth noting that some JRE parts cache that value, like the Java 7 `java.lang.System.lineSeparator()` does. To get a consistent behavior, that property should be specified at startup time.

Comment: I never though about this actually. I still think this answer is the best however, this does not change the behaviour of System.out.println() which will still output `\r\n`

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, I'd like to point out that changing the system property to something that is wrong can potentially  cause a lot of headaches, if you're using 3rd party libraries. Also keep in mind that this change is JVM-wide, so it will effect everything running on that JVM, whether you intend to or not.

Comment: @Holger, sure, you are right. Using `-Dline.separator` is preferable. I however do not know how to pass `\n` from shell... I was just too lazy to try this.

Comment: @Andreas: As said, at some places that property is cached. In case of `System.out.println()` it’s the class `BufferedWriter` which does that caching. Specifying the property at the command line works.

Comment: as pointed out by @Andreas, you can use -Dline.separator=$'\n'

Comment: This is not working on Java 14. I did not check backwards to previous Java versions when it started to break, but unless the property is set on the command line, it definitely has not effect for me, neither with streams nor with writers.

Comment: BTW, does anyone know how to do this on Windows in IntelliJ IDEA run configurations? I found no way to escape a newline character in there.

Answer (score 2):

Because the accepted answer simply does not work, as others pointed out before me, and the JDK only initialises the value once and then never reads the property anymore, only an internal static field, it became clear that the clean way to change the property is to set it on the command line when starting the JVM. So far, so good.

The reason I am writing yet another answer is that I want to present a reflective way to change the field, which really works with streams and writers relying on `System.lineSeparator()`. It does not hurt to update the system property, too, but the field is more important.

I know that reflection is ugly, as of Java 16+ needs an extra JVM command line parameter in order to allow it, and only works as long as the internals of `System` do not change in OpenJDK. But FWIW, here is my solution - don't do this at home, kids:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.file.Files;

/**
 * 'assert' requires VM parameter '-ea' (enable assert)
 * 'Field.setAccessible' on System requires '--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED' on Java 16+
 */
public class ChangeLineSeparator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    assert System.lineSeparator().equals("\r\n") : "default Windows line separator should be CRLF";
    Field lineSeparator = System.class.getDeclaredField("lineSeparator");
    lineSeparator.setAccessible(true);
    lineSeparator.set(null, "\n");
    assert System.lineSeparator().equals("\n") : "modified separator should be LF";

    File tempFile = Files.createTempFile(null, null).toFile();
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))) {
      out.println("foo");
      out.println("bar");
    }
    assert tempFile.length() == "foo\nbar\n".length() : "unexpected file size";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows cmd: Credit jeb at https://superuser.com/a/1519790 for a technique to specify a line-feed character in a parameter using a cmd variable.  This technique can be used to specify the java line.separator.

Here's a sample `javalf.cmd` file

```
@echo off

REM define variable %\n% to be the linefeed character
(set \n=^^^

^

)

REM Start java using the value of %\n% as the line.separator System property
java -Dline.separator=%\n% %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Here's a short test progam.

```
public class ReadLineSeparator {
  public static void main(String... ignore) {
    System.out.println(System.lineSeparator().chars()
                       .mapToObj(c -> "{"+Character.getName(c)+"}")
                       .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining()));
  }
}
```

On Windows,
`java ReadLineSeparator` produces

```
{CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)}{LINE FEED (LF)}
```

`.\javalf.cmd ReadLineSeparator` produces

```
{LINE FEED (LF)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with:

```
String str = "\n\r";
System.out.print("yourString"+str);
```

but you can instead use this:-

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to get the [line seperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns
>   the same value - the initial value of the system property
>   line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it
>   returns "\r\n".

Comment: Ok so `out.println()` uses this method to add it's linebreak. But is there some way to change what the property `line.separator` returns? Tell java that you are targeting another platform maybe?

Comment: I downvoted becuase the question asked how to change the seperator, and you had just put how to get it, however since you updated your answer I decided to remove it as it looks a lot better now :)

Comment: @Andreas:- You may use the `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");` at the beginning of your code then!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Java SE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> To modify the existing set of system properties, use
> System.setProperties. This method takes a Properties object that has
> been initialized to contain the properties to be set. This method
> replaces the entire set of system properties with the new set
> represented by the Properties object.
>
> **Warning:** Changing system
> properties is potentially dangerous and should be done with
> discretion. Many system properties are not reread after start-up and
> are there for informational purposes. Changing some properties may
> have unexpected side-effects.

In the case of `System.out.println()`, the line separator that existed on system startup will be used. This is probably because [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) is used to terminate the line. From the documentation:

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns
> the same value - the initial value of the system property
> line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it
> returns "\r\n".

As Holger [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681534/java-change-system-new-line-character/22681891#22681891), you need to overwrite this property at startup of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The method `System.lineSeparator()` returns the line separator used by the system. From the documentation it specifies that it uses the system property line.separator.

Answer (score 0):

Checked Java 11 implementation:

```
private static void initPhase1() {
    lineSeparator = props.getProperty("line.separator");
}

public static String lineSeparator() {
    return lineSeparator;
}
```

So altering system property at runtime doesn't change `System.lineSeparator()`.

For this reason some projects re-read system property directly, see my answer: [How to avoid CRLF (Carriage Return and Line Feed) in Logback - CWE 117](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969268/how-to-avoid-crlf-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-logback-cwe-117/66766346#66766346)

The only viable option is to set system property during app startup.

For Bash it is as simple as: `java -Dline.separator=$'\n' -jar my.jar`.

For POSIX shell it is better to save that character in some variable first:

```
LF='
'

java -Dline.separator="$LF" -jar my.jar
```

If you are not sure debug it:

```
printf %s "$LF" | wc -c
1

printf %s "$LF" | od -x
0000000 000a
```

For Gradle I use:

```
tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    systemProperty 'line.separator', '\n'
}

bootRun {
    systemProperty 'line.separator', '\n'
}
```