# How to avoid CRLF (Carriage Return and Line Feed) in Logback - CWE 117

Tags: security, logback, carriage-return, linefeed, log-forging

I'm using Logback and I need to avoid CRLF(Carriage Return and Line Feed) when I log a user parameter.
I tried to add my class, which extends ClassicConverter, on the static map PatternLayout.defaultConverterMap but It didn't work.

Thank you,

Comment: Where is the CRLF coming from? How are you logging this? What does you pattern look like?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a custom layout as described in [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)

Custom layout:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

public class RemoveCRLFLayout extends PatternLayout {

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        return super.doLayout(event).replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
    }

}
```

Logback configuration:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
    <layout class="com.foo.bar.RemoveCRLFLayout">
        <pattern>%d %t %-5p %logger{16} - %m%n</pattern>
    </layout>
</encoder>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a quick solution we used a `%replace` expression in our pattern, to replace line feed and carraige returns found in the message.

Note this example is using a Spring Boot property to set the pattern, but you can use %replace in your Logback config file the same way.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger - %replace(%msg){'\n|\r', '_'}%n"
```

(A custom converter would have been my first choice, but I had trouble getting it to work with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Config. If you want to learn more about that approach, search the logback docs for `conversionRule`.)

Answer (score 0):

`ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants`;

```
public static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

`ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LineSeparatorConverter`:

```
public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR;
}
```

`package ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout`:

```
    defaultConverterMap.put("n", LineSeparatorConverter.class.getName());
```

So the proper way to ensure fixed line ending is the property `line.separator`.

The same implementation is for `java.lang.System.lineSeparator()`:

```
lineSeparator = props.getProperty("line.separator");
```